# Show that surface integral of absolute vorticity is constant over time

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

In a rotating frame the (unforced, incompressible) Euler equation is
$$
\frac{∂\vec{u}}{∂t}+\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\vec{u}=-\nabla\left(\frac{p}{\rho_0}\right)-2\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{u}+\nabla\left(\frac{1}{2}|\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{x}|^2\right)
$$
where $\vec{\Omega}$ is a constant vector (the angular velocity).

Taking the curl of this equation (and using suitable vector identities), I can show that the vorticity $\vec{\omega}=\nabla\times\vec{u}$ satisfies
$$
\frac{∂\vec{\omega}}{∂t}=\nabla\times\left(\vec{u}\times\vec{\omega}\right)+2\nabla\times\left(\vec{u}\times\vec{\Omega}\right)
$$
Now **I want to show that**, if $S_t$ is a material surface within the fluid, then **the following is true**
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{S_t}{\left(\vec{\omega}+2\vec{\Omega}\right)\cdot d\vec{S}}=0
$$
I can write $$
\vec{\omega}+2\vec{\Omega}=\nabla\times\vec{u}+\nabla\times\left(\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{x}\right)
$$
and use Stokes' theorem to rewrite this as a line integral
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{S_t}{\left(\vec{\omega}+2\vec{\Omega}\right)\cdot d\vec{S}}=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{∂S_t}\left(\vec{u}+\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{x}\right)\cdot d\vec{l}
$$
but **here is where I am stuck**. I am given the hint (for any material curve $\gamma_t$)
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\gamma_t}\vec{a}\cdot d\vec{l}=\int_{\gamma_t}\frac{D\vec{a}}{Dt}\cdot d\vec{l}+\int_{\gamma_t}a_i\left(∂_ju_i\right)dl_j
$$
But when I substitute $\vec{a}=\vec{u}+\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{x}$ here nothing seems to become clearer.

Comment: What does $u$ stand for in the last equation?

Comment: @Elad the velocity (not angular)